# Как просуммировать значения в 2 словарях Swift

Tags: swift, словари

Даны два словаря, объедините их в один с названием `tables`. Если в обоих словарях будет один и тот же ключ, суммируйте значения.

```
let table1 = ["box": 3, "lamp": 1, "pen": 2]
let table2 = ["box": 2, "PC": 1, "pen": 3]
```

Comment: Попытайтесь для начала решить самостоятельно и приложите свой вариант если не получится

Comment: У меня не получилось именно значения просуммировать

Comment: смотрите мой ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, у нас дано два словаря (цифры подставил разнообразнее и побольше, чтобы проверить ответы):

```
let table1 = ["box": 4, "lamp": 2, "mac": 50, "apple": 12, "pen": 8]
let table2 = ["PC": 3, "pen": 22, "apple": 6, "box": 10, "phone": 5]
```

Первое задание сделал так (просто добавляем ключ-значение второго словаря в первый, если их ещё в нём нет):

```
let tables = table1.merging(table2) { (_, new) in new }
print(tables.keys)

//На консоль выйдет ["mac", "box", "pen", "lamp", "phone", "PC", "apple"]
//Здесь стоит иметь ввиду, что со значениями (цифрами) никаких операций не 
производится!
```

Вторая задача, логика и решение такие:

1. Создаём первый цикл, в котором узнаём ключ и значение из первого словаря
2. Создаём второй цикл, в котором узнаём ключ и значение из второго словаря
3. Сравниваем ключи. Если они равны, то складываем значения по этим ключам

   ```
    for (keyOne, valueOne) in table1  {
        for (keyTwo, valueTwo) in table2 {
            if keyOne == keyTwo {
                let sum = valueOne + valueTwo

                print(sum) //На консоль выйдут 14, 18, 30
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Задача может быть решена с помощью метода `merging`, его замыкание выполняет сложение, если ключи в словарях дублируются

```
let table1 = ["box": 3, "lamp": 1, "pen": 2] 
let table2 = ["box": 2, "PC": 1, "pen": 3]

var tables = table1.merging(table2) { v1, v2 in v1 + v2 }

print(tables)
```